# Reopen request for question 311304

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-request

[How to find a given game room in all TS3 servers?](https://superuser.com/questions/311304/how-to-find-a-given-game-room-in-all-ts3-servers) is a question about a desktop software, how to operate it. It's not about gaming, and it's not about Google searches. Why was it closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mention of Civ 5 might have triggered the offtopic votes, edited & reopened.